# php associative array deferencing

Tags: php, arrays, web-scraping

I created an imdb **scraper** in php. The **scraper** first **scrapes** the top 'n' number of movies and their top 15 casts as listed on imdb and then on entering the name of any actor and a number'm' it would display the top 'm' movies of that actor.
Following is the code for the same

```
<?php
$temp = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
$limit = fgets($temp);
$num=1;
$url= 'http://www.imdb.com/chart/top';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
//$docmovie = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

while($num<=$limit)
{
  $str = "//*[@id=\"main\"]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[".$num."]/td[2]/a";
  $span = $selector->query($str)->item(0);
  $movie = $span->nodeValue."<br>";
  //echo "<br>".$movie."<br>";
  $url_movie = $span->getAttribute('href');
  $url_movie = "http://www.imdb.com".str_replace("?ref_=chttp_tt_".$num,"",$url_movie)."fullcredits";
  @$doc->loadHTMLFile($url_movie);
  $select = new DOMXPath($doc);
  $str = "//*[@class=\"cast_list\"]";
  $span = $select->query($str)->item(0);
  for($x=2;$x<17;$x++)
  {
    $table = $doc->getElementsByTagName('table')->item(2)->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(2+(4*($x-2)));
    $actor =  $table->nodeValue."<br>";
    if($arr[trim($actor)][0]==NULL)
      $arr[trim($actor)][0]=0;
    $arr[trim($actor)][++$arr[trim($actor)][0]]=$movie;
    //var_dump($arr[$actor]);
  }
  $num++;
}
var_dump($arr);
if($arr['Morgan Freeman'][0]==NULL)
  echo "Actor not in list";
else
{
  $limit=$arr['Morgan Freeman'][0];
  for($x=1;x<=$limit;$x++)
  {
    echo $arr['Morgan Freeman'][$x]."<br>";
  }
}
?>
```

Here I input 5 as the initial number of movies which puts "The Shawshank Redemption" and "The Dark Knight" as movies for "Morgan Freeman"..$arr stores these values as can be seen from the result of var_dump($arr); But still when I query $arr['Morgan Freeman'] it gives out "Actor not in List"...
Can somebody please help me understand why is it happening?

Output of var_dump($arr) is

```
array(69) { ["Tim Robbins 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(28) "The Shawshank Redemption
" } ["Morgan Freeman 
"]=> array(3) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> string(28) "The Shawshank Redemption
" [2]=> string(19) "The Dark Knight
" } ["Bob Gunton 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(28) "The Shawshank Redemption
" } ["William Sadler 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(28) "The Shawshank Redemption
" } ["Clancy Brown 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(28) "The Shawshank Redemption
" } ["Gil Bellows 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(28) "The Shawshank Redemption
" } ["Mark Rolston 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(28) "The Shawshank Redemption
" } ["James Whitmore 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(28) "The Shawshank Redemption
" } ["Jeffrey DeMunn 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(28) "The Shawshank Redemption
" } ["Larry Brandenburg 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(28) "The Shawshank Redemption
" } ["Neil Giuntoli 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(28) "The Shawshank Redemption
" } ["Brian Libby 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(28) "The Shawshank Redemption
" } ["David Proval 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(28) "The Shawshank Redemption
" } ["Joseph Ragno 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(28) "The Shawshank Redemption
" } ["Jude Ciccolella 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(28) "The Shawshank Redemption
" } ["Marlon Brando 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(17) "The Godfather
" } ["Al Pacino 
"]=> array(3) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> string(17) "The Godfather
" [2]=> string(26) "The Godfather: Part II
" } ["James Caan 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(17) "The Godfather
" } ["Richard S. Castellano 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(17) "The Godfather
" } ["Robert Duvall 
"]=> array(3) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> string(17) "The Godfather
" [2]=> string(26) "The Godfather: Part II
" } ["Sterling Hayden 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(17) "The Godfather
" } ["John Marley 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(17) "The Godfather
" } ["Richard Conte 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(17) "The Godfather
" } ["Al Lettieri 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(17) "The Godfather
" } ["Diane Keaton 
"]=> array(3) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> string(17) "The Godfather
" [2]=> string(26) "The Godfather: Part II
" } ["Abe Vigoda 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(17) "The Godfather
" } ["Talia Shire 
"]=> array(3) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> string(17) "The Godfather
" [2]=> string(26) "The Godfather: Part II
" } ["Gianni Russo 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(17) "The Godfather
" } ["John Cazale 
"]=> array(3) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> string(17) "The Godfather
" [2]=> string(26) "The Godfather: Part II
" } ["Rudy Bond 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(17) "The Godfather
" } ["Robert De Niro 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(26) "The Godfather: Part II
" } ["Lee Strasberg 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(26) "The Godfather: Part II
" } ["Michael V. Gazzo 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(26) "The Godfather: Part II
" } ["G.D. Spradlin 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(26) "The Godfather: Part II
" } ["Richard Bright 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(26) "The Godfather: Part II
" } ["Gastone Moschin 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(26) "The Godfather: Part II
" } ["Tom Rosqui 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(26) "The Godfather: Part II
" } ["Bruno Kirby 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(26) "The Godfather: Part II
" } ["Frank Sivero 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(26) "The Godfather: Part II
" } ["Francesca De Sapio 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(26) "The Godfather: Part II
" } ["Christian Bale 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(19) "The Dark Knight
" } ["Heath Ledger 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(19) "The Dark Knight
" } ["Aaron Eckhart 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(19) "The Dark Knight
" } ["Michael Caine 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(19) "The Dark Knight
" } ["Maggie Gyllenhaal 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(19) "The Dark Knight
" } ["Gary Oldman 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(19) "The Dark Knight
" } ["Monique Gabriela Curnen 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(19) "The Dark Knight
" } ["Ron Dean 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(19) "The Dark Knight
" } ["Cillian Murphy 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(19) "The Dark Knight
" } ["Chin Han 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(19) "The Dark Knight
" } ["Nestor Carbonell 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(19) "The Dark Knight
" } ["Eric Roberts 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(19) "The Dark Knight
" } ["Ritchie Coster 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(19) "The Dark Knight
" } ["Anthony Michael Hall 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(19) "The Dark Knight
" } ["Tim Roth 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(16) "Pulp Fiction
" } ["Amanda Plummer 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(16) "Pulp Fiction
" } ["Laura Lovelace 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(16) "Pulp Fiction
" } ["John Travolta 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(16) "Pulp Fiction
" } ["Samuel L. Jackson 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(16) "Pulp Fiction
" } ["Phil LaMarr 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(16) "Pulp Fiction
" } ["Frank Whaley 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(16) "Pulp Fiction
" } ["Burr Steers 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(16) "Pulp Fiction
" } ["Bruce Willis 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(16) "Pulp Fiction
" } ["Ving Rhames 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(16) "Pulp Fiction
" } ["Paul Calderon 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(16) "Pulp Fiction
" } ["Bronagh Gallagher 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(16) "Pulp Fiction
" } ["Rosanna Arquette 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(16) "Pulp Fiction
" } ["Eric Stoltz 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(16) "Pulp Fiction
" } ["Uma Thurman 
"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(16) "Pulp Fiction
" } }
```

Output of print_r($arr) is

```
Array ( [Tim Robbins 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Shawshank Redemption
) [Morgan Freeman 
] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => The Shawshank Redemption
[2] => The Dark Knight
) [Bob Gunton 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Shawshank Redemption
) [William Sadler 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Shawshank Redemption
) [Clancy Brown 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Shawshank Redemption
) [Gil Bellows 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Shawshank Redemption
) [Mark Rolston 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Shawshank Redemption
) [James Whitmore 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Shawshank Redemption
) [Jeffrey DeMunn 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Shawshank Redemption
) [Larry Brandenburg 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Shawshank Redemption
) [Neil Giuntoli 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Shawshank Redemption
) [Brian Libby 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Shawshank Redemption
) [David Proval 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Shawshank Redemption
) [Joseph Ragno 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Shawshank Redemption
) [Jude Ciccolella 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Shawshank Redemption
) [Marlon Brando 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Godfather
) [Al Pacino 
] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => The Godfather
[2] => The Godfather: Part II
) [James Caan 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Godfather
) [Richard S. Castellano 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Godfather
) [Robert Duvall 
] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => The Godfather
[2] => The Godfather: Part II
) [Sterling Hayden 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Godfather
) [John Marley 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Godfather
) [Richard Conte 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Godfather
) [Al Lettieri 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Godfather
) [Diane Keaton 
] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => The Godfather
[2] => The Godfather: Part II
) [Abe Vigoda 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Godfather
) [Talia Shire 
] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => The Godfather
[2] => The Godfather: Part II
) [Gianni Russo 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Godfather
) [John Cazale 
] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => The Godfather
[2] => The Godfather: Part II
) [Rudy Bond 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Godfather
) [Robert De Niro 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Godfather: Part II
) [Lee Strasberg 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Godfather: Part II
) [Michael V. Gazzo 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Godfather: Part II
) [G.D. Spradlin 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Godfather: Part II
) [Richard Bright 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Godfather: Part II
) [Gastone Moschin 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Godfather: Part II
) [Tom Rosqui 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Godfather: Part II
) [Bruno Kirby 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Godfather: Part II
) [Frank Sivero 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Godfather: Part II
) [Francesca De Sapio 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Godfather: Part II
) [Christian Bale 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Dark Knight
) [Heath Ledger 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Dark Knight
) [Aaron Eckhart 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Dark Knight
) [Michael Caine 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Dark Knight
) [Maggie Gyllenhaal 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Dark Knight
) [Gary Oldman 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Dark Knight
) [Monique Gabriela Curnen 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Dark Knight
) [Ron Dean 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Dark Knight
) [Cillian Murphy 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Dark Knight
) [Chin Han 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Dark Knight
) [Nestor Carbonell 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Dark Knight
) [Eric Roberts 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Dark Knight
) [Ritchie Coster 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Dark Knight
) [Anthony Michael Hall 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => The Dark Knight
) [Tim Roth 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => Pulp Fiction
) [Amanda Plummer 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => Pulp Fiction
) [Laura Lovelace 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => Pulp Fiction
) [John Travolta 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => Pulp Fiction
) [Samuel L. Jackson 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => Pulp Fiction
) [Phil LaMarr 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => Pulp Fiction
) [Frank Whaley 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => Pulp Fiction
) [Burr Steers 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => Pulp Fiction
) [Bruce Willis 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => Pulp Fiction
) [Ving Rhames 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => Pulp Fiction
) [Paul Calderon 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => Pulp Fiction
) [Bronagh Gallagher 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => Pulp Fiction
) [Rosanna Arquette 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => Pulp Fiction
) [Eric Stoltz 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => Pulp Fiction
) [Uma Thurman 
] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => Pulp Fiction
) )
```

Comment: can you print_r($arr); and show the results ? then we can check whats going wrong

Comment: I just edited the question to include the outputs of var_dump($arr) and print_r($arr)..Could you try to reason out the problem now?

Comment: well i think this is because there is a array in a array i think u should use echo arr[0][1] to get the title

Comment: thats what I have used...I used $arr['Actor Name'] to store name of actor $arr[][0] to store the number of movies he is in and $arr[][1...m] to store the Title of the movie he has acted in..

Answer (score 0):

I promised to check.. so i checked.. I could not use the fopen etc because of limitations so i made a array model just like urs.. with 2 names.. i have rewritten some stuff just to get you in the right direction please cchck http://pastebin.com/uuYCEgYu

heres the code:

```
// DEMO ARRAY
$arr = Array();

$arr['Tim Robbins']  = Array ();
array_push($arr['Tim Robbins'],'1','The Shawshank Redemption');

$arr['Morgan Freeman']  = Array ();
array_push($arr['Morgan Freeman'],'2','The Shawshank Redemption', 'The Dark Knight');
//print_r($arr);
//DEMO ARRAY END


//LOOP ARRAY
foreach ($arr as $key=>$data) {
  echo $key, "<BR>"; // = actor name

  //MATCH ACTOR NAME
  if ($key = 'Morgan Freeman') {
    echo 'actor found<BR>';  

    //THERE IS A MATCH SO SHOW DATA
    foreach ($arr['Morgan Freeman'] as $data) {
      echo $data;
    }

  } else {
    echo 'actor not found<BR>';
  }

}
```